# How does Swift type inference affect compile and run time?

Tags: swift, performance, compiler-optimization

```
var number = 3
```

vs

```
var number: Int = 3
```

How does using specific types vs type inference affect compile time? Has anyone done experiments or some math on this topic?

Does this runtime affect at all in anyway?

Answer (score 5):

Compile time: In most cases, this will be trivial. In your example, 3 is an integer literal; integer literals can adapt to their use, but it's trivial that number will have type Int.

At runtime, there is absolutely no difference. Both statements are 100 percent equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples will do the same.
differences appear when using float values.

```
var double = 2.5
var float : Float = 2.5
```

In swift its better to write less code. This makes the code healthier and for sure it will be faster.

Comment: Why would you be using Float instead of Double?

Comment: this indicates withou setting : Float it will do a double when putting in 2.6